# How to retrieve the Url and Description of a hyperlink column as separte entities?

Tags: 2010

I want to retrieve the Url and the Description of a Hyperlink column in SP 2010 for data processing.

In the current scenario the field holds a link to an employee website as the URL and the name of the employee as the Description.

My only idea at this time is to use the following regex

```
^(?<URL>(https?://[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*),\W(?<Description>.*)
```

So for a value like
http://spd2010/firstname.lastname, Firstname Lastname

I get URL `http://spd2010/firstname.lastname1` and Description `Firstname Lastname`

Is there any other way? It would be nice to know a best practice of some sort for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SPFieldUrlValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurlvalue.aspx) is the class you are looking for.

This class exposes both the Url and the Description